# MYSQL - start and end time of overlapping periods

Tags: mysql, time, range, overlap, simultaneous

I have a table with several events and their starting and ending date/time.
Below I have a sample data with **4 events which overlaps simultaneosly** in different periods of time.
For each period they overlap I should apply a multiplying factor to its duration.

**What I've got so far:** 
I am using MySQL as a database;
I have a table with spatial index on the start/end date/time which I use with MBRIntersects to find overlaps among the events. The method works pretty fine, and I got rid of those many ifs and joins.
Thus, I can get the intersection start/end time of each event individually. But that doesn't help much. 
I need to find the start/end time of the overlapping periods, so I can group them and apply the maximun factor in that range.

Maybe I am taking the wrong approuch.

**What I cannot do so far:** Find the start/end times of the overlapping periods. In the example shown I need to get intervals like so:

- 1 | 08:00 | 08:15
- 2 | 08:15 | 09:30
- 3 | 09:30 | 10:00
- 4 | 10:00 | 10:15
- 5 | 10:15 | 10:30
- 6 | 10:30 | 11:00

[image: Multi overlap model]

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: If you get all the start times and all the end times, and union them all, you should get a list of all timestamps that will be the start times of all periods. You would just need to get the last end date and copy the start times to finish the previous periods.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @EdmCoff MySQL 8.
I will try that. Thanks

Comment: @EdmCoff
It wouldn't work as I also need a split between 10:15 and 10:30. It's not a starting overlap, but it's when the calculation should change as there are two overlaps between 10:15 and 10:30

Comment: @EdmCoff, your answer was very usefull. Actually I had to union all start/end times and then I used Window function to put them together in a start/end table. Thanks a lot!